# Which plugin or language are used in this web site?

Tags: jquery

I saw this website : [Lancôme](http://www.lancome.fr//_fr/_fr/ecommerce/services/DiagCils/index.aspx) and I want to do the same thing in another website. I mean I want to ask the customer like this website to know which product will be the best for him at the end of the "form" (if we can call something like that a form).

My question is how can I do something like that ? Which language I have to use  : JQuery?Javascript ? Do a plugin exist to make it ?

If someone know a template that I can download and modificate don't hesitate.

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: just see open source in web site for these questions. http://www.lancome.fr/_fr/_fr/ecommerce/medias/scripts/scripts.aspx?page=services&jqversion=1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

The website you linked is .NET, and includes some jQuery and jQuery UI libraries (and neither is close to the latest version either).

If you're asking these questions then I would suggest finding a web developer that knows his job, and get him to write it for you.

Comment: I just wanted to know if any plugin exist to do this or something like this, I will change it but I can't pay a web developer to write it for me. Thanks anyway :)